# The partial view '_RdsInfoView' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where on loading the page, system displays a dropdownlist with values filled in it.So, I've added a view to display those things.

Upon selection of any values, it shall display the details of the selected item.
So I wrote action for it which returns a partial view.

I got issue, system throwing is an exception saying "PartialView was not found" though I gave the entire path in one of the Views.

View1:-

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RenderDataStore";
}

<h2>RenderDataStore</h2>

@Html.DropDownList("Claim Versions", ViewBag.Versions as SelectList, "Select", new {
id = "ddl", onChange="dropDownSub()"
})

<div id="forRdsInfo">
    @Html.Partial("~/View/DropDownList/RdsDetails.cshtml")
</div>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#ddl").on("change", function () {

            $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/DropDownList/RdsDetails?rdsHdrSeqNo=' + $(this).attr("value"),
                type: 'GET',
                data: "",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#forRdsInfo").html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        })
    })

</script>
```

Partial View:-

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.RdsHeaderModel

<fieldset>
    <legend>EmployeeModel</legend>
    <div class="display-label">
        <strong> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.rdsHdrSeqNo) </strong>
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.rdsHdrSeqNo)
    </div>
    <div class="display-label">
        <strong> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.info) </strong>
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.info)
    </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Controller:-

```
public class DropDownListController : Controller
    {
        // GET: DropDownList
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult DatabaseDropDown()
        {
            Repository repo = new Repository();
            var getClaimVersions = repo.GetClaimVersion().ToList();
            SelectList list = new SelectList(getEmpVersions, "rdshdrseqno", "claim_version");
            ViewBag.Versions = list;
            return View();
        }

        public PartialViewResult RdsDetails(long rdsHdrSeqNo)
        {
            Repository repo = new Repository();
            RdsHeaderModel rm = new RdsHeaderModel();
             rm.rdsInfo = repo.GetRdsInfo().ToList();
            var filteredData = rm.rdsInfo.Where(x => x.rdsHdrSeqNo == rdsHdrSeqNo).FirstOrDefault();
            return PartialView("~/View/DropDownList/RdsDetails.cshtml", rm);
        }
    }
}
```

System is throwing the exception in View1 saying that " It doesn't find any of the Partial View" in the

```
<div id="forRdsInfo">
    @Html.Partial("~/View/DropDownList/EmpDetails.cshtml")
</div>
```

Could anybody help me with a solution.

Comment: i don't see `_RdsInfoView` anywhere in your code, do a global search `Ctrl+Shift+F` pick `Entire Solution`, and search for  `_RdsInfoView`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a super long shot, but you're certain "~/View/DropDownList/RdsDetails.cshtml" shouldn't be "~/Views/DropDownList/RdsDetails.cshtml", right?

Also I can't see where you're passing any parameters/models to RdsDetails. Your @Html.Partial("~/View/DropDownList/RdsDetails.cshtml") doesn't seem to be passing any parameters.